# Using Node-Geocoder with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to use Node-Geocoder in my typescript application, using the DefinitelyTyped type definitions found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node-geocoder). What I am wondering is how I am supposed to pass my configuration options to the Node-Geocoder instance. I would think you use it similar to how you use the library in Javascript, by passing the options to the constructor of the Geocoder object. However, that is giving me an error stating that the constructor does not take any arguments.

```
import DomainServiceInterface from "./../DomainServiceInterface";
import NodeGeocoder from "node-geocoder";
import LocationServiceInterface from "./LocationServiceInterface";

 export default class LocationService implements DomainServiceInterface, LocationServiceInterface {

    private geocoder: NodeGeocoder.Geocoder;

    constructor() {
        const options: NodeGeocoder.BaseOptions = {
            provider: "google",
            // other options
        };
        this.geocoder = new NodeGeocoder.Geocoder(options);
    }

    // other methods here
 }
```

I attempted to look this up. However, all tutorials and content I could find related to Node-Geocoder are in Javascript.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fair warning, I've never used the node-geocoder package.

If you look at the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node-geocoder/index.d.ts#L135), the export is a function, not a class.  (Technically [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) is used to export a function and a namespace.) That function takes `Options` and instantiates a `Geocoder` instance.

That said, you would create a `Geocoder` like this.

```js
import * as NodeGeocoder from 'node-geocoder';

const options: NodeGeocoder.Options = {
  provider: "google",
};

const geoCoder = NodeGeocoder(options);
```